# Highcharts: Y-Axis Grid Lines Misaligned

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to create a chart in Highcharts with multiple data series, with different y-axes for each series. This works fine using the standard functionality (an array of y-axis definitions) for linear charts. However, when one of the y-axes is defined to be logarithmic, the grid lines and axis labels become misaligned.

JSFiddle code demonstrating issue: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zplizzi/8JkGa/)

I would like for the "Rainfall" axis to have labels at positions corresponding to the labels on the "Temperature" axis. I can simply set `gridLineWidth: 0` to hide the offending gridlines from view, however the labels are still misaligned. Is there a simple way to solve this? I have attempted a solution using the `tickPositioner` functionality but it seems to be a complicated solution to what should seemingly be a common problem.

Comment: logartihm axis has no regular interval between ticks, so you cannot align these both types.

Comment: Even with a logarithmic axis, it should be possible to calculate values for the second axis labels that correspond with the position of the first axis labels/gridlines - although the labels may not be integar values, there should be a mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a workable (but non-ideal) solution to my problem using the `tickPositioner` function:

```
tickPositioner: function () {
                if (this.tickInterval > .5) { 
                    return null;
                }
                else {
                    var myInterval = (this.max - this.min) / 5;
                    return [this.min, this.min + myInterval, this.min + 2 * myInterval, this.min + 3 * myInterval, this.min + 4 * myInterval, this.max];
                }
            }
```

The `if` clause checks if the HighCharts library will automatically set the tick interval to powers of 10 (which are already spaced evenly), and if not, simply manually sets the ticks in set intervals (in this case, 5 evenly spaced ticks). This works for a log scale because the tick position values are set before the logarithm is taken - allowing even interval tick values to end up evenly spaced on a log plot.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that they ar not lining up is that your logrithmic axis isn't starting at zero. You can't have zero on a log axis, but you can get close by setting a min of 1.

```
 , { // Secondary yAxis
        min:1,
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4LKW2/

However, if you want to force the min and max values, I think you will have to use a tickPositioner or tickPositions e.g.

```
tickPositions:[Math.log(24)/Math.log(10),Math.log(42)/Math.log(10),Math.log(73)/Math.log(10),Math.log(129)/Math.log(10),Math.log(225)/Math.log(10),Math.log(400)/Math.log(10)],
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SWrd6/

Comment: I don't want to start my axis at zero - for example, if my data ranges from 10,000 to 100,000 this would create a lot of unnecessary white space on the chart. I can't set fixed axis values either as the data is dynamic and the range of the chart will need to auto-scale. I will look further into `tickPositioner`, although it is proving difficult.